# Как добавить плагин advanced Ajax product filter на другие страницы сайта wp?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Первый раз сажаю сайт на wp (никогда не делал этого так как все делаю руками)
Установил плагин advanced AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce by BeRocket
[плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/) фильтр цены с ползунком

До этого сделал атрибуты и применил их к товарам на сайте (woocommerce установлен)

Дело в том, что в сайдбар я вывел этот плагин, но он отображается только и только на "главной странице магазина" ([главная](http://%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/catalog/page/4/?filters=order-popularity%7Cprice%5B500.00_8939.00%5D)) и тут вроде как все отлично работает, но этот плагин НЕ отображается вообще на других страницах - я создал страницу "батареи салютов", прикрутил туда тот же сайдбар и вот уже на этой и подобных страницах этот плагин не отображается. [второстепенная](http://%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/batarei-salutov/)

Так как я в wp не сидел, прошу знатоков помочь мне разобраться почему плагин не отображается на других страницах. кроме "главная магазина"

***Вот код шаблона catalogs.php, который сделал специально для страниц категорий товаров (в шаблоне вывожу сайдбар точно также как и на главной странице иагазина, всё идентично), а уже в сам контент добавляю шорткододы вукамерс чтобы на странице отображались товары из определенной категории***

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Catalogs
*/
?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH. "/header2.php"); ?>
<!-- Начало врапер -->
<section id="wrapper">
<div id="middle">
<div id="content">
<div id="colLeft">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- Начало .singlecont -->
<article class="singlecont">
<div class="cont">
<div class="content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<div class="left-filters">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- Конец .синглконтент -->
</div>
<!-- Конец colleft -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

***Шаблон page.php (это же шаблон главной страницы магазина где сайдбар работает как часы)***

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH. "/header2.php"); ?>
<!-- Начало врапер -->
<section id="wrapper">
<div id="middle">
<div id="content">
<div id="colLeft">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- Начало .singlecont -->
<article class="singlecont">
<div class="cont">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<div class="left-filters">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- Конец .синглконтент -->
</div>
<!-- Конец colleft -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

***sidebar-left.php код***

```
<section> <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) { ?>
<div>Нет виджетов</div>
<?php } ?>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Плагин запускается всегда, на всех страницах сайта. Не отображается он потому, что на других страницах нет сайдбара. Возможно, его нет в шаблоне страницы (в php коде)

Comment: Я же написал что на другие страницы я вывел тот же самый сайдбар

Comment: Это вам кажется, что вы его вывели. На главной магазина есть `<div class="l-sidebar"`, а на второстепенной его нет. Поясните, что вы сделали для ого, чтобы вывести этот сайдбар на второстепенной странице.

Comment: У страниц магазина зачастую используется другой сайдбар, например Woocomerce sidebar (все зависит от вашей темы). На других страницах должен быть выбран шаблон страницы с сайдбаром, нужно проверить что не выбран шаблон Fullwidth. Сделайте скрин страницы с виджетами, чтоб вам смогли подсказать

Comment: @eugene_v здравствуйте. У меня своя тема для wp, то есть html код интегрировал под wp. Да, на других страницах выбран тот же шаблон что и на главной. Скрин добавил в вопрос

Comment: @KAGGDesign для того чтобы этот же сайдбар вывести на нужные страницы, для этих "нужных" страниц я создал свой шаблон. И туда тоже добавил кусок кода, который есть и на той странице где сайдбар отображается <div class="left-filters">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-side' ); ?>
</div>

Comment: Вот этот код и не работает. Выложите целиком код этого шаблона, чтобы понять, где у вас ошибка.

Comment: И мне кажется, что он должен называться left-sidebar. Сравните с кодом на главной странице магазина

Comment: @KAGGDesign проверил код идентичен и там и там, создал новый файл sidebar-left.php по имени id сайдбара. И нифига

Comment: @KAGGDesign обновил вопрос

Comment: Что-то у вас все разъезжается. Ссылка на главнй страницу магазина теперь не работает - 404. Выложенный код не соответствует тому, что я вижу на сайте. В кода sidebar-left.php есть <section>...</section>, на сайте этого нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77075/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).